# Python - editing local HTML files - Should I edit all of the content as a one string or as an array line by line?

Tags: python, html

Just to be clear this is **not** a scraping question.

I'm trying to automate some editing of similar HTML files. This involves removing content between tags.

When editing HTML files locally, is it easier to open() the file then dump the content line by line into a string so it's easier to apply a regular expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For structured markup like HTML, it is better to use a parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) than regular expressions. A few reasons for this include better results for malformed HTML and decreased complexity (you don't need to reinvent the wheel).

Considering the question at face value though, it seems easier to split the HTML up into lines using [readlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines) so that you are dealing with only one line at a time when applying regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks I realized that after I posted this question and hopefully I don't get flamed for it. I'm trying HTMLParser but I'll check out BeautifulSoup.

The reason I'm not going line by line is because I'm trying to delete data between tags. The tags are separated by 1 or more lines.

Comment: Most tags spanning multiple lines would be either simple tags that you can recombine. Regular expressions across a whole HTML file work when those files are small, but grow complicated as pages grow, especially for pages with a lot of nested divs.

Comment: Thanks, I've found that BeautifulSoup's HTMLfile.tag.decompose() works great for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of creating your own templating language (which is what this task amounts to), you use one of the many which already exist, and use that to perform the necessary operations. Try Jinja2, Django Templates, or Cheetah to see what you fancy. There are also many others.